# Mysql left join query returns values NULL

Tags: mysql

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT img.prd_id,prd.*,img.* FROM products_prd prd OUTER JOIN 
prd_images_img img ON prd.prd_id=img.prd_id ORDER BY prd.prd_datetime
```

the primary key in products_prd is returned NULL. They have values. while img.prd_id may be NULL or not.

Comment: Please provide us with create table statements plus some sample data.

Comment: I assume your join should be `LEFT OUTER JOIN` based on the title of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have name collisions -- two things called `prd_id` for example.  You need to use aliases to rename the columns:

```
SELECT prd.*, img.col1 as img_col1, img.col2 as img_col2
FROM products_prd prd LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     prd_images_img img 
    ON prd.prd_id = img.prd_id
ORDER BY prd.prd_datetime;
```

You don't need to select `prd_id` twice.

Or, you can use `USING` instead of `ON`:

```
SELECT *
FROM products_prd prd LEFT OUTER JOIN 
     prd_images_img img 
     USING (prd_id)
ORDER BY prd.prd_datetime;
```

This returns the columns in the `USING` clause only once (although you could have problems with other columns if they have the same names in the two tables).

Comment: Thanks man with a little modification your suggestion worked.